# servicefactories accessed from componet factory in OSGI

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, service-factory

I am using component factory to create a multiple unique instances which in-turn uses services which is servicefactories to create multiple instance. 
My structure looks like
TInterface - interface/service
TInterfaceInline - which implements TInterface also consists of @Reference for another service.
Tinterfaceimpl1 - extends TInterfaceInline which is a servicefactory  with filter property.
TConsumer - component factory which consumes the TInterfaceInline
by getting it in @Reference.

TConsumer

```
@Component(name = "TConsumer", factory = "TConsumer")
@Service
public class TConsumer implements IConsumer {

    // @Reference(bind = "bindInterface1", unbind = "unbindInterface1", target =
    // "(className=Interface)")
    // private Tinterface interface1;

    @Reference(referenceInterface = ParentProfile.class, bind = "bindInterface11", unbind = "unbindInterface11", target = "(className=interface1)", policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC, cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY)
    private ParentProfile interface11;

    @Activate
    public void activate(BundleContext aBundleContext) {
        System.out.println("Object = " + interface11);
    }

    protected void bindInterface11(ParentProfile interface11) {
        this.interface11 = interface11;
        System.out.println("ref object11 created");
    }

    protected void unbindInterface11(ParentProfile interface11) {
        interface11 = null;
    }
```

TinterfaceImpl

```
@Component(name = "TInterfaceImol")
@Service(serviceFactory = true,value=ParentProfile.class)
@Properties(value = { @Property(name = "className", value = "interface1") })
public class Tinterfaceimpl1 extends TinterfaceInline  {

    public Tinterfaceimpl1() {
        System.out.println("Generalprofile class : " + this);
    }
}
```

TinterfaceInline

```
@Component(name = "TinterfaceInline ")
@Service
public class TinterfaceInline implements java.io.Serializable, ParentProfile {
    // @Reference(bind = "bindtestin", unbind = "unbindtestin", cardinality =
    // ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC)
    public Testint testin;

    protected synchronized void bindtestin(Testint inter) {
        this.testin = inter;
        System.out.println("Profile Class : binded parameterresolver " + testin);
    }

    protected synchronized void unbindtestin(Testint inter) {
        this.testin = inter;
    }

}
```

ParentClass

```
@Component(name = "PResolver")
@Service
public class ProfileClass implements Testint {
    public ProfileImpl() {
        System.out.println("Parameter class impl  : which extends ");
    }
}
```

Apart from this remaining things are marker interfaces. If i try to install in karaf , the state of the Tinterfaceimpl1 is REGISTERED. ie) i am using servicefactories and accessing service factories from component factory. Servicefactory class extends a class which implements Interface. What is the reason Tinterfaceimpl1 is REGISTERED.

Comment: The OSGi has now standardized the annotations, it looks like you use the old SCR annotations? It might also help to use an example that shows more clearly what you want to do in the real world. I find it very hard to understand the idea behind the code.

Comment: @Peter My requirement is a class mentioned as a factory has some reference services which inturn mentioned as servicefactory. Whenever a component factory creates an instance corresponding reference objects should be created  uniquely. that's why i have mentioned as service factory to make them unique.

Comment: I think I had an idea what your question is. I'm just puzzled what real world use case is for the required complexity. I've used DS for ten years and have had only about 2 use cases so far for component factories :-(

Comment: My use case is some of the components should be registered themselves as factories(componentfactory), which inturn uses some sort of services(servicefactory), which should be unique. While creating a new instances factory should produce new instance with unique service instances.

Comment: The problem is that your problem is in YOUR solution to an underlying problem ... Since I am quite experienced in this area and NEVER needed to revert to the kind of complex solution you came up with I am curious what incredibly complex end-user problem you're trying to solve ... I expect the solution to the end-user problem could be a lot simpler.